# skipping a readline and repeating unlimited times with arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, for-loop

when i run it skips the first readline and repeats the first "for" unlimited times
at first it gave me the nullreferenceexception error , thats when i added the first line in the first for
i'm new to coding so please let the solution be simple

this is the code :

```
class People
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public int age;


    public void setvalues(string na, string ad, int ag)
    {
        this.name = na;
        this.address = ad;
        this.age = ag;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of People you want to add : ");
        int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

        People[] plist = new People[q];
        string[] namelist = new string[q];
        string[] addresslist = new string[q];
        int[] agelist = new int[q];


        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        {
            plist[i] = new People();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the person :      ");
            namelist[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the address of the person :   ");
            addresslist [i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the age of the person :   ");
            agelist[i] =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int s = 0; s < q; s++)
        {
            plist[s].setvalues (namelist[s], addresslist[s], agelist[s]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care when using `Console.Read()` and `Console.ReadLine()`.

`Read()` only reads the first availabe character. All other (available) characters are left in the input buffer.

`ReadLine()` reads until it finds a line-end character (typically `\n`).

So when the user enters the value for `q` and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `Read()` only reads the first character, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is already stored in the buffer. This <kbd>Enter</kbd> is then read by the `ReadLine()` before the user has a chance to enter the appropriate value for that line.

I think your best option is to replace your first `Read()` with a `ReadLine()`, too.